# How to interpret nu and tau in GAMLSS BEINF?

Tags: r, gamlss

My response data is a ratio going from 0 to 1, inflated at 0 and 1.

My aim is to build an explanatory model to test the influence of PROTECTION and JOUR (categorical fixed factors) on the response Ratio.
I used GAMLSS to fit a model with the beta inflated distribution.
I read that *The beta inflated distribution is a four parameter distribution.
It is similar to the beta but allows zeros and ones as values for the response variable. The two extra parameters model the probabilities at zero and one.*
The parameters of the model are mu, sigma, nu and tau, so I understand that nu and tau are parameters related to the probability of ratio=0 and ratio =1.
What I don't understand is that mu, sigma, nu and tau are always used to fit a gamlss. Thus, even a beta distribution without the binomial part for 0 and 1 does have nu and tau parameters.
So, how to interpret the estimates of nu and tau ?

Here is the best fitted model for my data:

```r
gamlss(formula = Ratio ~ PROTECTION, sigma.formula = ~1,  
    nu.formula = ~JOUR + (re(random = ~1 | BRANCHE_NB)),      tau.formula = ~(re(random = ~1 | BRANCHE_NB)),  
    family = BEINF, data = D_E1, trace = FALSE)
```

(BRANCHE is a random factor used because the same branches are sampled every day)

The summary gives, for nu :

```r
Nu link function:  log 
Nu Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  -1.8495     0.6224  -2.972  0.00434 **
JOUR1         1.5213     0.7484   2.033  0.04676 * 
JOUR2         1.5425     0.7637   2.020  0.04814 *
```

Does it means that JOUR1 and JOUR2 have significantly higher Ratio =0 than JOUR3 (the intercept level) ?
Or does it gives information about the influence of the levels of JOUR on the value of ratio when it is different from 0 too?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a beta regression model to always have inflation parameters for 0/1. These values are not within the domain of the beta distribution however, so if they occur within your data you'd be wise to extend your model for it. You can fit a two-parameter mu, sigma beta regression with the `BE` family.

You can check the parametrization of your model via `?gamlss.dist::BEINF`, very briefly $p_0$ and $p_1$ are the probabilities of 0 and 1 occuring respectively, $p_2 = 1 - p_0 - p_1$, $\nu=\frac{p_0}{p_2}$, and $\tau=\frac{p_1}{p_2}$ (both log-linked by default). This means that increasing values of the parameters indeed reflect higher probabilities. In your example JOUR3 as a predicted probability for 0 of $e^{-1.8495}\approx 0.157$, and JOUR1 is $e^{-1.8495 + 1.5213}\approx 0.72$.

edit: oops, the above probabilities are only relative by a factor of $p_2$, but you'll have to know $p_1$ to calculate that.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It brings me to another question : in the same process, I used the function StepGAIACallA to choose the best fitted model. The model with the lower AIC has sigma~1 (and no other fixed nor random factor). Thus, I am wondering if beta inflated was the good distribution to choose, as the parameter sigma is not dependent from my explicative factors in the best fitted model. I choose the beta inflated distribution because the histogram of my response data looked like it, but does sigma~1 in the best fitted model means that BEINF is not adequate ?

Comment: There's many ways to approach model selection, though the choice between regular beta and zero/one-inflated beta should really depend on your data (i.e. whether zero or one can actually occur in it). The best fit for the mu/sigma parameters have a very different meaning, you can interpret these as location/scale (mean/variance) in this model. The fact that sigma~1 produces an apparently good fit suggests that the variance is relatively constant across your effects (i.e. no heteroscedasticity), though I would certainly also graphically explore this.

Comment: Thank you ! Just one last thing: in my best fitted model tau~random variable, which is the branch on which the ratio was counted every day of the trial. the estimate is -18.49 and the standart error is high (1540), does it means that there is a big variaition in p1 across the branches ? I really appreciate your help because self learning is hard

Comment: I just saw your edit and I am not sure I got it : JOUR3 having a predicted probability for 0 of 0.157 means that 1-p1 = 0.157 or 1-p1-p2 = 0.157 ?

Comment: No, to get the actual predicted probability for 0 you also need to know tau or p1. The parameter nu is log(p0/p2), so the predicted probability p0 is exp(nu / [1 + nu + tau]) - not exp(nu) like I wrote before. Still, the interpretation won't change in that larger values of the parameters are larger probabilities, only the absolute magnitude of those probabilities is incorrect.